# Separable ODE, $x'(t)=1+x(t)^2, \quad t\geq 0$ - Where am I going wrong?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that the function $x(t)=tan(t+C)$, $C\in\mathbb{C}$, solves the separable ODE $x'(t)=1+x(t)^2, \quad t\geq 0$. But when I tried to solve to ODE in a normal manner I got the following:

$$x'(t)=1+x(t)^2,\quad t\geq 0\Leftrightarrow \frac{x'(t)}{1+x(t)^2}=1,\quad t\geq 0 \color{red}{\Leftrightarrow} \int \frac{x'(t)}{1+x(t)^2} dt=\int1dt,\quad t\geq0.$$

The equality on the right side of the red equivalence arrow bothers me to no end, since the LHS should be:

$\arctan(x(t))$,

and the RHS should be

$t+C$, for some $C\in\mathbb{C}$, for any positive value of $t$.

However, $\arctan$ does not take values outside of the interval $\left(-\pi/2,\pi/2\right)$, whereas $t+C$ obviously takes values outside that interval for some values of $t\geq0$.

I'm clearly making some elementary mistake in my thinking here, but I'm not figuring out how my question should be resolved in a good manner. At first I thought that one could split up the positive numbers into intervals of length $\pi$ and take different constants $C$ for each interval, but that just seems stupid, and wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that $\tan$ has poles at the odd multiples of $\pi/2$.  Thus a solution $x = \tan(t+C)$ is really only valid on an interval of length $\pi$, say $m \pi/2 - C < t < (m+2) \pi/2 - C$ where $m$ is an odd integer.  Despite being given by a formula that looks the same, $x = \tan(t+C)$ on one of these intervals and $x = \tan(t+C)$ on another are not really the same solution.

The interval $m \pi/2 - C < t < (m+2) \pi/2 - C$ corresponds to $- \pi/2 < t + C - (m+1)\pi/2  < \pi/2$, and thus $t + C' = \arctan(x)$ where $C' = C - (m+1)\pi/2$.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: But there seem to be a few $C$'s missing in the open intervals, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks.